# Running time of algorithm with two different operations

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have an algorithm with two operations. 1st operation running time is O(n) and running time for 2nd operation is O(log n). In this situation what will be the running time for complete algorithm ? will it be O(n) or O(n) + O(log n) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`O(n + log(n)) = O(n)`

Your time complexity will be O(n)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: You're messing too freely with big-O notation. Though the answer is correct, the question was about `O(n)+O(logn)`, not about `O(n+logn)`. That's subtle but can be important

Comment: I may say mistakes, but as said on the wiki article : if f1 is `O(g1)` and f2 is `O(g2)` then f1+f2 is `O(|g1|+|g2|)`.

Comment: That's right, and that's the reason your answer is correct. But (following your example) the question was about O(g1)+O(g2), not about O(g1+g2).

Comment: I'm not sure : there are two operations. T1(n) (function that give the time needed to compute the first algorithm) is `O(n)` and T2(n) is `O(log(n))`, so if we consider T1+T2 (the function that give the time needed for the whole algorithm), then we can say it is `O(n + log(n))`.

Comment: T1+T2=O(n)+O(logn)=(due to the reason you quote!)=O(n+logn)=O(n). Again, this is an important subtlety. Your answer would've been suitable if the question was about a single algorithm that executes in `O(n+logn)` time.

Answer (score 4):

Total time is `O(n) + O(logn) = O(n)`. So it's `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

`O(logn)` in relation to `O(n)` decreases exponentially with N, so it is `O(n)`.